# How to access Steam chat logs?

Tags: steam

How can I read my old conversations with my Steam friends?

Facebook and Google Chat (whatever it's called now) let me review old conversations

Comment: December 2022:
Steam does not retain a chat history for you beyond a day or two. The Steam Chat mobile app does not grant access to historical chats any more than the desktop client.

Answer (score 7):

Steam does not log your chats, at least not on your local machine, though their new EULA agreement does allow them to review your chat logs, they are stored on their servers or hidden in encrypted files on your desktop as no one has yet discovered them.

It is possible to log your chat via 3rd party support however as it requires some of your steam details, I cannot guarantee it's security and therefore will not post a link to it.

Comment: Giving a 3rd party your Steam login details (which are required to gain access to your conversations) is **very bad**. Don't even consider doing it.

Comment: I agree, I'm not sure it needs all your log-in details, I think just your username but it sounds dodgy so while in the interest of full disclosure I have referenced it, I wont post a link to one as showing preference could suggest endorsement which I do not.

Comment: Can definitely access message history now, via mobile app - at least on iOS.  This is 2017 though, not 2012 :)

Comment: @Dmitriy Per your [proposed edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/766818): that Steam has added a new method for obtaining recent chat logs is worthy of a new answer

Answer (score 6):

If you have the [Steam mobile app](http://store.steampowered.com/mobile), you can access previous messages sent to and from Steam friends in chat.

Once you install the mobile app and log in, select the hamburger menu (on iOS and Android, click the friends tab on Windows Phone), and then press `chat`.

Select the user you want to chat with.

Comment: iOS user here. I got to it by opening the hamburger menu and then going Friends -> {click on friend in list of friends} -> Send a Message.  This included messages sent from my PC (I never use the mobile app for chat).  So I'm assuming messages are stored on the Steam servers.

Comment: This won't show your entire history, just the most recent ~200 messages

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all anymore.